# Change div background on an alert button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently trying to set the background of a div on a `jquery ui alert dialog` button click event. The user clicks a button and that brings up the dialog where the user chooses an image from a `select` option. When they hit the `Choose Background`( The button that is part of  a `jqueryUI dialog alert`). It should change the div `class=”middle-side”” background. I have done this before but the button is part of the html element. I have done this regular buttons but not part of dialog. How can I change the background of the div on alert button click? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/Lnwth1uj/1/) - P.S. Issue with jsfiddle showing images from an external source

jQuery:

```
$('#backgroundPick').click(function (e) {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete all items": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- Triggers and shows Alert Dialog -->
<button id="backgroundPick">Choose Background</button>

<!-- Alert Dialog -->
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Choose Background">
    <select class="image-picker show-labels show-html">
        <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
        <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
        <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
        <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Display background here -->
<div class="middle-side"></div>
```

Comment: Re-word your question and its title. The `jQuery UI Dialog widget` has nothing to do with the `Vanilla Javascript Alert Dialog`.

Comment: i just noticed that your question is kind of strange. why do you want to change the background as soon as someone hits the "change background" button? in this particular moment you can't know what background the user will choose in the upcoming dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would remove the creation of the dialog from the click function, by initializing with `autoOpen: false`.  This makes your code cleaner and also doesn't leave your dialog code in the DOM tree until the user clicks "Choose background".

Second, I assume you want the first button to be "Change background", not "Delete all items".

So, to answer your question, in your callback for the button, grab the data for `img-src` in the `:selected` option.  Then set the background image of the `.middle-side` div:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 230,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false, // Initialize the dialog, but don't open it
    buttons: {
        "Choose background": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            var img = $('#dialog-confirm select option:selected').data('img-src');
            $('.middle-side').css('background-image', 'url("'+img+'")');
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$('#backgroundPick').click(function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog( "open" ); // Open the dialog on click
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ohdbu94y/

Comment: it repeats the image, is there a way to make it 100% width and height?

Comment: Add `background-size: 100%;` to your `.middle-side` css.  http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ohdbu94y/1/

Comment: You can also do `background-size: cover` which is basically the same thing, or `background-size: contain`, which will make it as big as possible without cropping.  In that case, you would also want `background-repeat: no-repeat`, and possibly `background-position: center`.  http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ohdbu94y/2/

Answer (score 0):

just add an even listener to your `<select>`:

```
$(document).on("change", ".image-picker", function(){
    $(".middle-side").css("background", $(this).data("img-src"));
});
```

**edit:** as i mentioned in my comment, your question doesn't really make sense. you want to change the background as soon as someone hits the "choose background" button. but this button opens the dialog which lets you choose an image. you can't change the background before you even know what the user is going to select.